# Angular2: UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Could anybody tell me why npm is getting me this message when I perform `npm install`:

```
+-- @angular/common@2.2.4
+-- @angular/core@2.2.4
+-- @angular/http@2.2.4
+-- @angular/platform-browser@2.2.4
+-- @types/core-js@0.9.35
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
| `-- symbol-observable@1.0.4
`-- zone.js@0.6.26
```

What's `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY`?

The content of `packages.json` is:

```
{
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.2.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
 }
}
```

Why `npm` is trying to resolve `rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4` instead of `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.2.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  }
}
```

Just remove that `^`